# Which plugin group should my plugin belong to

Tags: plugins, joomla

This is a general question about writing Joomla plugins. When you create a plugin, you have to assign it to a group, either existing or a new custom group.

From what I understand the following points hold:

- For a plugin to respond to an event that plugin's group must be loaded at the point the event is fired. `JPluginHelper::importPlugin('group_name');`
- Events belong to groups, but this is only really a logical grouping; an event could be fired even if its group was not loaded.
- A single plugin can respond events from multiple groups.

If the above is correct then does this mean that you would assign a new plugin to a group which you know will be loaded when the event your are interested is triggered?

What reasons would I add my plugin to a new group rather than adding it to an existing group?

Answer (score 0):

The big impact of putting plugins into groups is that at some points whole groups are loaded and that is a separate kind of behavior than listening for a trigger.   So if your plugin wants to be part of what happens when a particular group is loaded you should put it in that group. Otherwise it does not matter what group you put it in except that it might be tidier in some way.

Why would you want to make a group of your own? Because your component (or other extension) is going to load its own group. The reason to do that is that maybe other people will want to write plugins to be triggered by your component. Many of the more complex components do this.

Why are groups sometimes loaded? 
In some situations you want to be able to cycle through a number of possibilities until you get success (or failure).  So the authentication process starts with the first authentication plugin and cycles through them until you get either a successful login or a real failed login.  This is why the order of plugins matters.

Another situation is the content plugins, which are kind of a weird special case. These plugins only run when a content extension calls the content plugins.  All they do, their entire purpose, is to embed something inside content so you would not want them running all the time.

A third situation is system plugins. These are plugins what will run on every single pageload. You only would put a plugin in the system group if you need it to run really early and every time ... you don't want a lot of these and you would avoid the system group if you possibly can because even with all the improvement to plugin performance, there is still a performance hit. Plus sometimes there are unpleasant surprises when a plugin you meant only for the frontend is running in the backend.

A fourth situation is the finder and search plugins. In these cases the plugins relate to very specific functionality in specific components and the plugin groups allow extension developers to create their own plugins to run at the same time.

So it's really a matter of what your plugin does.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for adding plugin to particular group is a set of events, which this groups is listens to. For example, only "user" group listens to "onUserBeforeSave" and "onUnserLoginFailure" events. So when adding plugin to some group you must be sure it supports events you're trying to work with. Plain and simple.

Comment: It's not so much listening as the group is explicitly loaded. Usually that is because you are going to cycle though a particular group until you get success such as authentication or cache. that's why order of the plugins within groups matters.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. If you check, you'll find that the onUserBeforeSave event is listened to by the profile plugin which is in the user group and the languagefilter plugin, which is in the system group. Even in my question I suggest that plugins can listen to events from different groups.

Comment: onUserBeforeSave event for "system" group is never triggered in "user" model or any other place in Joomla code and never used, no matter, whether it exists in any "system" group plugin or not. You may add ANY event to ANY plugin from ANY group, but this doesn't mean this event will ever be fired. So yes, my answer is absolutely correct.